# Let ChartJS time axis switch to quarters or years

Tags: date, time, chart.js, axis

I create line charts with a time-based x-axis. My minimum unit is day.
I configure the axis like this (Python syntax):

```
'scales': {
'x': {
    'type': 'time', 
    'time': {
        'round': True,
        'minUnit': 'day',
        # 'unit': 'quarter', 
        'displayFormats': {'year': 'YYYY', 'quarter': '[Q]Q YYYY', 'month': 'MMM YYYY', 'day': 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
        'tooltipFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    },
    'grid': {
        'drawOnChartArea': False,
        'tickColor': '#BBB',  # '#DDD'
    },
    'ticks': {
        'autoSkip': False,
        'autoSkipPadding': 20,  # padding between the labels before they rotate
},
...
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of line chart]

Here's my question: why doesn't the time axis switch to quarters, unless I fix it to quarters using `'unit': 'quarter'`? It would be so much easier to read.

Actually, I would like a setting to use a stepSize of 1 without multiples. That means, all days, months or quarters should be shown, when the unit is that respective mode. If the labels are too close, the automatic should choose the next available unit. Is there a way to do this? From the documentation, it sounds as if `autoSkip: false` should to the trick, but I can't see a difference.

Thanks for any help!